# Split line into the different lengths from attribute table data

Tags: qgis, line, table, splitting

Is it possible in QGIS to split one line in one direction into multiple segments of varying length which I have in the attribute table?

For example: overall line is 10 m long, in table I have data: 1.5m, 2.8m, 3m,.. In this order will the line be split to specific follow-up lengths in table.

Comment: Please be more specific about the way your data looks. Do you have multiple layers? Or are the segment lengths in an attribute of one line? Also show what you have tried before and didn't work.

Comment: My idea is only make it manually with the tool measure. 
I have shapefile with 15 lines of roads, with no atributtes. My colleague give me an excel file, where are described traffic signs placed on the roads. Placing of traffic signs is described by lenght (each traffic sign is placed in specific lenght from the beginning of the road/line). So I need to create point layer of traffic signs or split the line to parts between single traffic sign.